# How override `this` in the mongoose.Schema.prevalidate middleware?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, middleware

I don't understand why my model instance is not **overrided**:

```
schema.pre('validate', function(callback: any, done: any){
    if(!this.status){
        var Type = __Dao.getModel('type');
        Type.findOne({name: 'processing', 'category.name': 'languageStatus'}, function(err, role){
            if(err){
                callback(err);
            }else{
                console.log('this: '+JSON.stringify(this))
                this.status = role;
                callback();
            }
        });
    }
    done();
});
```

**Console**:

```
this: {"domain":null,"_events":{},"_maxListeners":10,"emitted":{"complete":[{"code":"a","name":"processing","_id":"52fd475c699127802d298665"}]},"ended":false}
```

// Other console.log
    { message: 'Validation failed',
      name: 'ValidationError',
      errors: 
       { status: 
          { message: 'Path `status` is required.',
            name: 'ValidatorError',
            path: 'status',
            type: 'required',
            value: undefined } } }

I checked and my `role` is not empty.
I think my mistake is on the `this.status = role;`, `this` is defined but it looks like I don't override it in the good way.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Don't you need to also save it after setting the status? When does the second log line happen?

Comment: The second line happens when I try to save a fake model, in my `app.js`. Should I save it? How? It's not a model, isn't? just call `this.save()`? I thought that I just needed to change the object and it would have been saved automatically. I don't know really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned it doesn't look like `this.status` is the right object.  It also looks like you might be using parallel middleware incorrectly.
[Middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) can be defined as serial `Schema.pre('save', function (done) {...` or parallel `Schema.pre('save', true, function (next, done) {...`.  Notice the second arg is a boolean indicating that it should be run parallel.

For parallel try the following:

```
schema.pre('validate', true, function(next, done){
    var self = this; // save a reference to status
    next();  // start working on any other middleware in parallel with this one

    if(!self.status){
        var Type = __Dao.getModel('type');

        return Type.findOne({name: 'processing', 'category.name': 'languageStatus'}, function(err, role){
            if(err){
                done(err);
            }else{
                console.log('status: '+JSON.stringify(status))
                self.status = role;
                done();  // signify this middleware's work is done
            }
        });
    }
    done();
});
```

If that doesn't work you could try to use serial middleware, to make sure you don't have conflicts in other middleware.

UPDATE: the differences between parallel and serial is only going to matter when you have more than one piece of middleware.  Parallel gives you the ability to run all middleware at the same time, and then move on to the actual validation after all are done.  Serial will do the first piece of middleware, and wait to start the next piece after the previous one is done, then validating once all are finished.

For an example, image your client service is running on a machine that has to send requests to the database across a network.  The time might not be accurate, but for discussion lets assume those requests take about 100ms.  Using Serial middleware:

```
Schema.pre('validate', function (done) {
    Type.findOne({ name: 'steve' }, function (err, doc) { // send request across network
        // ~100ms later we get steve
        // pre validate steve ...
        done(); // Start the next piece of middleware after this is done
    });
});

Schema.pre('validate', function (done) {
    Type.findOne({ name: 'Jim' }, function (err, doc) { // send request across network
        // ~100ms later we get Jim
        // pre validate Jim ...
        done(); // Start the next piece of middleware after this is done
    });
});
```

Total time == ~ 200+ms

If you run them parallel the requests to the database can go at nearly the same time.

```
Schema.pre('validate', true, function (next, done) {
    next(); // start the next piece of middleware before sending request
    Type.findOne({ ... }, function (err, doc) { // send request across network
        // ~100ms later we get the doc
        // do stuff ...
        done();
    });
});

Schema.pre('validate', true, function (next, done) {
    next(); // start the next piece of middleware before sending request
    Type.findOne({ ... }, function (err, doc) { // send request across network
        // ~100ms later we get the doc
        // do stuff ...
        done();
    });
});
```

Total time ~ 100+ms

Comment: I read the doc but honnestly I'm kinda lost with this `parallel` mode, I didn't really understand the whole thing, what's the difference between both and the provided args?

Comment: Does the `return` statement important here? findOne is synchronous.

Comment: Okay, so I did the changes but it still doesn't works. status is undefined before, but after `status = role;` he's defined. But I still get the validation error.

Comment: The return is important, because findOne is Asynchronous.  I just realized there is a mistake in my code I'll update

Comment: I was wondering about the `this` and how your code could update anything in the current instance ^^ It's better, I'll try.

Comment: Okay, it works! Thanks. But I still don't understand **how**. How return something asynchronous can have any effect? Do you have a link about that? It's pretty confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, do you know why it didn't work with the serial way? Btw, with your explanation, I dont see why use the serial way, except maybe when we need some dependencies to be loaded... But parallel looks better!

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the model and logging any errors from there. So after the line: `this.status = role;` do this:

```
this.save(function(err, info) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('Error saving the model:', err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Saved: ', info);
});
```

It might give you more info on has failed.

Comment: It looks like a hack for me, I mean, I will call the .save() that will call the .validate and inside I should call the .save that will also call the .validate, will pass the validation and then automatically call the .save ? Weird, no?

Comment: I tried, the this.save callback is not triggered, my console.log are not called at all.

Comment: But is there anything else in the error log? Obviously your validation is failing. Canyou show the whole validation code?

Comment: jwags solution works for me, using parallel. It doesn't works in serial and I don't have a clue about why.